# Google Sheets: Dynamic array formula that prints a date range into an array for each 'ID' entry

Tags: arrays, function, date, google-sheets, array-formulas

Hoping to get a single dynamic formula in Google Sheets that gives me the following:

**Scenario 1**

Input:

```
| ID | Date                   |
| 1  | Jan 1, 2023            |
| 2  | Jan 2, 2023            |
| 3  | Jan 3, 2023            |
|    | Jan 4, 2023            |
|    | Jan 5, 2023            |
```

Desired output:

```
ID  Date
----------------
1   Jan 1, 2023
1   Jan 2, 2023
1   Jan 3, 2023
1   Jan 4, 2023
1   Jan 5, 2023
2   Jan 1, 2023
2   Jan 2, 2023
2   Jan 3, 2023
2   Jan 4, 2023
2   Jan 5, 2023
3   Jan 1, 2023
3   Jan 2, 2023
3   Jan 3, 2023
3   Jan 4, 2023
3   Jan 5, 2023
```

**Scenario 2** (preferred)

Input:

```
ID  Start Date  End Date
----------------------------
1   Jan 1, 2023 Jan 10, 2023
2   Jan 5, 2023 Jan 10, 2023
3   Jan 8, 2023 Jan 10, 2023
```

Desired output:

```
ID  Date
---------------
1   Jan 1, 2023
1   Jan 2, 2023
1   Jan 3, 2023
1   Jan 4, 2023
1   Jan 5, 2023
1   Jan 6, 2023
1   Jan 7, 2023
1   Jan 8, 2023
1   Jan 9, 2023
1   Jan 10, 2023
2   Jan 5, 2023
2   Jan 6, 2023
2   Jan 7, 2023
2   Jan 8, 2023
2   Jan 9, 2023
2   Jan 10, 2023
3   Jan 8, 2023
3   Jan 9, 2023
3   Jan 10, 2023
```

You may see this [sample document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VZ4Ytpc_dqLgREGf7liC6zwW7NopMU0tHG9KDnYo-X8/edit?usp=sharing) for reference.

I was able to find a solution for the first scenario, but it doesn't seem efficient.

Given these inputs:

```
Date / ID   1   2   3
Jan 1, 2023         
Jan 2, 2023         
Jan 3, 2023         
Jan 4, 2023         
Jan 5, 2023
```

And with this formula,

```
=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA(split(transpose(split(TEXTJOIN("^",true,(B1:D1&"!"&A2:A6)),"^")),"!")),1, true, 2, true)
```

I was able to get this output:

```
Date / ID   1   2   3
---------------------------
Jan 1, 2023 1   Jan 1, 2023 
Jan 2, 2023 1   Jan 2, 2023 
Jan 3, 2023 1   Jan 3, 2023 
Jan 4, 2023 1   Jan 4, 2023 
Jan 5, 2023 1   Jan 5, 2023 
            2   Jan 1, 2023 
            2   Jan 2, 2023 
            2   Jan 3, 2023 
            2   Jan 4, 2023 
            2   Jan 5, 2023 
            3   Jan 1, 2023 
            3   Jan 2, 2023 
            3   Jan 3, 2023 
            3   Jan 4, 2023 
            3   Jan 5, 2023
```

This works but, as I mentioned above, a solution for scenario 2 is preferred.

Comment: could you share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result? You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: Here! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VZ4Ytpc_dqLgREGf7liC6zwW7NopMU0tHG9KDnYo-X8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution using `REDUCE`:

```
=ArrayFormula(
  REDUCE({"ID","Date"},
          FILTER(ROW(A4:C)-3,
                 BYROW(A4:C,LAMBDA(row,COUNTBLANK(row)=0))),
          LAMBDA(acc,cur,
                {acc;
                SPLIT(INDEX(A4:C,cur,1)&"❄️"&
                SEQUENCE(
                  INDEX(A4:C,cur,3)- 
                  INDEX(A4:C,cur,2)+1,1,
                  INDEX(A4:C,cur,2)),
                "❄️")})))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option combining two REDUCE with SEQUENCE and INDEX:

The first REDUCE is defined by the amount of items in A2:A `(SEQUENCE (COUNTA(A2:A)))` With that value `v` you'll be able to scan the values of columns A,B and C. So each time you use `INDEX(A2:A,v)` or similar you're accessing the item of that row from that column

The second REDUCE is defined by the amount of days of difference between C and B column, and basically adds one day at a time. Both REDUCE nested looks like this:

```
    =REDUCE({"ID","Date"},SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)),
LAMBDA(a,v,{a;
REDUCE({INDEX(A2:A,v),INDEX(B2:B,v)}, SEQUENCE (INDEX(C2:C,v)-INDEX(B2:B,v)),
LAMBDA(b,w,{b;INDEX(A2:A,v),INDEX(B2:B,v)+w}))}))
```

[image]